# How to go back to previous page using Javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, back

I have the following scenario:

I have the following script in my page:

```
function GoBackToPreviousPage () {           
   parent.history.back();
   return false;
}
```

In Code Behind I have the following

```
If (some conditions are met)
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GoBackToPreviousPage", "GoBackToPreviousPage();", true);
```

If the conditions are met I want the page to go back to the previous page, 
the reason I'm doing this in javascript instead of on the server
is because (parent.history.back();) maintains a history of all the previous pages

I noticed that the after the RegisterStartupScript is executed and postback happens the script is executed but it stays on the same page, it does not go back to the previous page

Comment: Why are you using the `parent` property?

Comment: I have the same problem if I use: history.back() without the parent

Comment: And what about `history.go(-1)`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the PostBack that occurs before the execution of the javascript function. You click the button and the current page is saved in the browser history. So, when the page reloads and the script executes, you are in the same page. So, a not-so-pretty solution is to go back two pages in history:

```
function GoBackToPreviousPage() {
    window.history.go(-2);
    return false;
}
```